# Angularjs http requests slow due to socket.io

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, socket.io, angular-socket-io

Hoping someone might have experienced this before and can offer a solution. I have an application that runs on Express, Nodejs and Socket.io server with Angularjs frontend. It looks like whenever there's an Angular http request and socket.io event in parallel, the http request gets blocked until the socket event is completed. As you can see, data as small as 5 and 15kb takes 15+ seconds. This delay in http requests occurs on localhost as well as when proxied through nginx server on Windows/Linux and any other environment I've tried.

[image]

```
// Angular Factory

app.factory('socket',['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var socket = io.connect('', {
        path: static_path + '/socket.io',
        transports: ['websocket']
    });
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        },
        disconnect: function(close){
            socket.disconnect(close);
        },
        removeAllListeners: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.removeAllListeners(eventName, function() {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

And I have my express, socket.io server set up this way...

```
// Express and Socket.io server

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var Server = require('socket.io');

// $(staticPath) is just path variable
var io = new Server({
    path: `${staticPath}/socket.io`,
    transports: ['websocket']
  });

io.listen(http);

http.listen(8080);
```

It makes no difference whether I use transports option or remove it